# ISO7816 over ISO1443 NFC Smartcard Read Austrian E-Card Personen Grunddaten returns SW1:69 Sw2:82

Tags: nfc, smartcard, apdu

I am trying to read Personen-Grunddaten from an Austrian EHIC ECard.

With the help of an outdated Project called [Mocca](https://github.com/primesign/mocca/blob/master/smcc/src/main/java/at/gv/egiz/smcc/STARCOSCard.java) and the following document [tuwien-TR0174.pdf](https://www.auto.tuwien.ac.at/bib/pdf_TR/TR0174.pdf) I was able to gather the necessary APDUs to Read the data from a Generation 3 and 4 Ecard (Cards without NFC or Person Image). With some tweeking I could eventually even read G5 cards (NFC enabled) (they somehow have stricter APDUs (with G3 or G4 cards you can specify whatever return-length, use CASE4 even though card expects CASE1 etc.))

After successfully reading the Person Name etc. from an NFC enabled card through the physical smartcard interface I tried reading the contents through NFC. However when I send the APDU to Read the binary content, I receive SW 69 82 -> Security condition not satisfied.

These are my APDUs:
Everything Up to Read-Binary data works fine and returns 90 00 or some data. The responses are exactly the same when comparing NFC and Smartcard mode.

- Select-MasterFile, Select, 00-A4-00-0C, Case1
- Select-Application SV_PERSONENDATEN, Select, 00-A4-04-0C-08-D0-40-00-00-17-01-01-01, Case3Short
- Select-Function FID_GRUNDDATEN, Select, 00-A4-02-04-02-EF-01-00, Case4Short
- Read-Binary Data, ReadBinary, 00-B0-00-00-00, Case2Short

Do I have to authenticate myself to the card somehow when in NFC reading mode? Official apps such as [Ecard-Self Check in](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.co.svc.app.android.oss)  (does not currently work) or the physical card readers with NFC functionality (GINO) do not need any user input. The only possible answer to this is that the card reader has to send something to the card to authenticate and enable data reading in NFC mode.

I have tried to look for an answer in the German equivalent but have not found anything about NFC reading and authentication with EHIC cards and what APDUs are available for this task.

Thank you for any answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need, that *you* (as card holder) authenticate, but the requestor as well as the card terminal must do so in case of NFC communication, see [eCard specification](https://www.chipkarte.at/cdscontent/?contentid=10007.886544&portal=ecardportal). It is pretty standard, that contactless communication requires additional security mechanisms (as session key negotiation for subsequent encryption), so the information can't be easily intercepted.

While the command for reading does not change, the access rule can enforce these additional security mechanisms via interface-dependent access rules.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, interesting, but (Ecard specification)[https://www.chipkarte.at/cdscontent/?contentid=10007.886544&portal=ecardportal] contradicts the way the app Ecard-Self Check in should work. This app should be able to (is currently broken) read the ecard. Also _Die Verwender der Lesegeräte müssen sich mit einer Berechtigungskarte authentifizieren_ is incorrect since you do not need a socalled Ocard to read an Ecard via NFC. Do I understand you correctly that I have to send an additional command to authenticate?

Comment: @peerfunk: If the desired functionality is, to authenticate the terminal, you are unlikely to have access to the keys for performing the same task with an entirely different terminal type.